# Is it ok to switch wires from gauge 12 to 14 inside a box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Inside a multi-gang box I have a hard time working with the 12-gauge wire. Is it ok to connect them with a wire nut to a 14-gauge and then connect to the switches.

The box has switches to light, heater, humidifier. The circuit breaker is 20 amps. The current wiring is 12 gauge everywhere it seems. This is in a small bathroom in TX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not!  You need 12 AWG for enough wire thickness so you don't set the wires on fire.

What you should do is two things.

1. Use "screw-and-clamp" type switches and outlets.  These allow you to back-wire, but without the reliability problems of backstabs (which only take #14 anyway.
2. Once you have done that, if that is not enough to solve your problem, then pigtail, yes-- but with **#12 *stranded*** wire.

This is sold as individual wires called "THHN".  Many shops sell it by-the-foot.

Stranded is a sheer pleasure to work with.   However, it's illegal on backstabs and almost impossible for a novice to competently put on a side screw.  So, the "Screw-and-clamp" devices make that work out.

If you fall in love with THHN stranded, you can use it anywhere *as long as it's inside conduit*.  Smurf tube, PVC or EMT metal.  If you run metal, that serves as the ground.   You can put up to 4 circuits into a conduit, and it makes it easy to do things like 3-way circuits that need always-hot and neutral for onward stuff.

Comment: Interesting, i did not know that stranded wire was allowed. Seems like more of a pain for the connections then a heavier gauge.

Comment: @AlaskaMan That's precisely why I said to use screw-and-clamp switches/outlets.  Once you do that, stranded is easy-mode.  I work almost exclusively in #12 stranded, I own 10 colors of it in THHN (don't own any #14).

Comment: I really like the screw/clamp type outlets, very secure, safe for both solid and stranded.   A few years ago, HD was closing out spools of 10 ga solid, so I bought some.   Worst purchase ever!  You're right, stranded is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Unless you change the breaker protecting that circuit to 15 amp and mark the wires. I made the mistake of running 12 ga wire for lighting when I built my house 15 years ago. LEDs didn't exist then and CFLs were awful.  Yeah, it's hard to work with and could I do it over again, I'd go with 14 ga for lighting.  Breakers are matched to the wire gauge to protect the circuit, not the device, so if you change part of the "circuit", even if in a small way like inside the box, it's not code compliant.   The weird part is often dimmers and smart switches have 16ga or less and that's OK?!

Comment: UL requires the devices be engineered so it's vanishingly unlikely they will out-draw their #16 wire.  Also UL won't let them make the wires long enough to matter.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Good to know, interesting. I've always thought it was odd that fixtures, dimmers, smart switches, etc. could have smaller gauge wire than the over current protection for the circuit. I realize the wires are inside a box, but still.   Thanks for posting this.